# php run method and get variable in one line

Tags: class, variables

I want to get variable after running class function. I usually do it in 2 lines:

```
    $object->function();
    $var = $object->function_variable;
```

Can I do it somehow in one line?

```
    $var = $object->function()->function_variable;
```

UPDATE

In general I want to call for different vars from one function in different files

```
    $var = $object->function()->function_variable1;

    $var = $object->function()->function_variable2;

    $var = $object->function()->function_variable3;
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about this

Comment: Do you mean instance_variable?

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't function() easily return your function_variable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about the basics of  oop,
If the function returns the value that you want to assign to $var, then you can do:

```
$var = $object->function();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to access **instance variable** not function variable. So it will be like:

```
$var = $object->function()->instance_variable;
```

For this to work your function should **return an object** with those instance variables, then only you will be able to achieve this.

For more clarity see the below example:

```
<?php

class Name
{
  public $fname, $lname;

  function __construct($fname, $lname)
  {
    $this->fname = $fname;
    $this->lname = $lname;
  }
}

class Person
{
  private $name;

  public function __construct($fname, $lname)
  {
    $this->setName($fname, $lname);
  }

  public function getName()
  {
    return $this->name;
  }

  private function setName($fname, $lname)
  {
    $this->name = new Name($fname, $lname);
  }
}

$p = new Person('Raj', 'Mishra');
$name = $p->getName();
print $var = $name->fname;         // $var = $object->instance_variable1;
print " ";
print $var = $p->getName()->lname; // $var = $object->function()->instance_variable2;

?>
```